# Emulate a keyboard via USB to USB

Tags: usb, keyboard, kvm-switch

I know this is twisted, but hear me out.

I am trying to use a Raspberry Pi as a KVM over IP via xvnc. Video output is easy, just using a video capture card, but I need to be able to connect a male to male USB from my Raspberry Pi and have it send signals to the machine being KVMd.

I suppose I could take a USB keyboard apart and use the chip from that, then emulate keypresses to that keyboard via GPIO pins on the Raspberry Pi, but that is just even more twisted haha.

Also: I know that the USB bus only works in one direction (ie, a controller can't be a device also) but I am open to USB => serial => USB type solutions or similar.

Comment: Why not just use synergy to emulate keypresses? I suppose you might be able to do this with a teensy or other avr chip with the right libraries, but there's no 'easy' way to do what you want.

Comment: I need BIOS level access on the host. (Synergy is awesome of course)

Comment: Could you not just use a USB Extender?

Comment: Get a gender bender, or extender...

Comment: A USB male to male cable exists, certainly. But the question remains of making computer A look like a keyboard to computer B....

Comment: Male to male cables are out of scope of USB specification. There is no sane use for them (well, there is if you only use them as power cables, but again, 2 wires isn't exactly USB).

Comment: I think I found a relevant topic on [electroncs SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/18888/can-i-get-the-chip-or-electronic-kit-of-a-usb-keyboard-alone-whithout-the-plasti). Take a note of it for your future twisted electronics-related questions.